# Activation of network connection failed (wifi)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I have a laptop which had ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed. Workerd perfectly fine for a couple of years.
Last week this issue started:

- when I startup the laptop, my wifi connects to my home network.
- I can ping all devices in my network, I can reach my NAS and play movies.
- the moment I start firefox my wifi connection drops, and my wifi adaptor isn't available anymore.
  I get the error: "Activation of network connection failed."
  I can't enable/disable the network adaptor anymore, I don't see any networks I'd suppose to see.
  I used a USB wifi adaptor, exactly the same issue.
  Over ethernet I don't have problems what so ever.

I already did a complete reïnstall to ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, still the issue remains.
did some suggestions I found online, but nothing helped:

- disabled 'connect automaticly'
- disabled  auto timezone
- reïnstalled the network manager
- disabled IPV6
- driver is most recent one

I'm running out of options, see I'm hoping someone on this board can help me :)

Kind regards,
Pieter

Comment: If you can connect to your local devices, your wireless connection on Ubuntu works properly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting. After I open firefox or chromium my wifi connection fails and I can't connect to my local devices anymore. The wifi adaptor isn't available anymore and the only option that worked is to reboot my laptop. Only to have the same issue the next time I open firefox or chromium